# Go app using Postgres array when selecting from Redshift table

Tags: go, amazon-redshift, pq

I have seen many examples online for using an array while selecting values from a table. This is the query I ran against Redshift.
`select * from table where colID = ANY(array[1])`
This query works fine when I ran it using SQL Workbench.

I am trying to run the same query in my Go app using https://github.com/lib/pq

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", url)
defer db.Close()

rows, err := db.Query(`select * from table where colID = ANY($1)`, pq.Array([]int{1}))
if nil != err {
        pqErr := err.(*pq.Error)
        fmt.Println(pqErr.Error())
}
```

The above code is expected to work according to https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Array.

But the output is an error.

```
-----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   IsA((Node*)arrayExpr->args->tail->data.ptr_value, Const) -
  query:     9574375
  location:  xen_execute.cpp:6200
  process:   padbmaster [pid=14680]
-----------------------------------------------
```

as the error and rows is `nil`

However the below code works

```
rows, err := db.Query(`select * from table where colID = ANY(array[1])`)
```

Can anybody explain why I am getting an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redshift supports `ANY('{1,2,3}'::integer[])`.
Reason why `db.Query('select * from table where colID = ANY($1)', pq.Array([]int{1,2,3}))` did not work is because, the value returned by `pq.Array([]int{1,2,3})` is `{1,2,3}`. However redshift expects it to be `'{1,2,3}'`. Changing the query to include the single paranthesis `''` 
`db.Query('select * from table where colID = ANY('$1')', pq.Array([]int{1,2,3}))`
around array does not work.

After trying few options, the below code worked!

```
v, _ := pq.Array([]int{1,2,3}).Value()
query := fmt.Sprintf(`select * from table where colID = any('%v'::integer[]);`, v)
rows, err := db.Query(query)
```

Answer (score 2):

The above is supposed to work with Postgres but Redshift is different and it doesn't have an array data type. Redshift supports ANY condition but in a different way, the parameter of the condition should be a set of rows, not an array:

```
select true where 1=any(select 1 union select 2 union select 3);
```

would return `true`, and

```
select true where 4=any(select 1 union select 2 union select 3);
```

would return nothing.

A set of rows can be a hardcoded `union` like above, or a result of a subquery, but not a comma separated list or an array.

Comment: Could you explain how `select * from table where colID = ANY(array[1])` executed successfully on redshift? 
If `ANY(array[])` was constantly failing then that would align with issues with redshift. But the query works with `ANY` if manaully pass in the array instead of passing the array as a parameter